# how to use "dbstat" table in a trigger in sqlite?

Tags: sqlite

i need to limit my table size to suppose 10 Mb using dbstat i want to create a trigger for the same but iam getting below error SQL error: unsafe use of virtual table "dbstat"

below is the trigger query:

CREATE TRIGGER less_den_ten_mb BEFORE INSERT ON mqtt6 BEGIN DELETE FROM mqtt6 WHERE timestamp=(select min(timestamp) from mqtt6 where 1=(SELECT sum(pgsize)>1024000 from dbstat where name="mqtt6")); end;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at [the source for the virtual table](https://www.sqlite.org/cgi/src/file?name=src/dbstat.c&ci=trunk) in its `statConnect()` function you'll see

```c
sqlite3_vtab_config(db, SQLITE_VTAB_DIRECTONLY);
```

And from deep in [the documentation](https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/c_vtab_constraint_support.html#sqlitevtabdirectonly):

> Calls of the form `sqlite3_vtab_config(db,SQLITE_VTAB_DIRECTONLY)` from within the the `xConnect` or `xCreate` methods of a virtual table implementation prohibits that virtual table from being used from within triggers and views.

So you're not allowed to use `dbstat` in a trigger. This is part of a security feature added in sqlite 3.31.0. There are [further details](https://www.sqlite.org/cgi/src/doc/87aea3ab1cdda453/doc/trusted-schema.md) on the rationale and reasoning if you're interested.